# How to change the color of a button?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I'm new to android programming. How do I change the color of a button?

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="55dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Button Text"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"/>
```

Comment: @theapache64 Maybe I don't research properly. But, I think subtle changes of UI for Android SDK and Material Design are documented not so straightly or even poorly. It's like sometimes you should rely on IDE hints, sometimes on documentation, sometimes on some stuff from forums like Stack Overflow. I came here after seeking in Material Design documentation.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can change the colour two ways; through XML or through coding. I would recommend XML since it's easier to follow for beginners.

**XML:**

```
<Button
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
/>
```

You can also use hex values ex.

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

**Coding:**

```
//btn represents your button object

btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: Would like to point out that its a good idea to use layout XML for this regardless of your experience level, especially if the color doesn't need to change. Hell even if it does change I would use layout binding.

Comment: don't use this - you'll lose the button animation (lift and ripple)

Comment: @SomeoneSomewhere that's right. See [the correct answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954610/7711481).

Answer (score 107):

#### The RIGHT way...

The following methods actually work.

**if you wish - using a theme**
By default a buttons color is `android:colorAccent`. So, if you create a style like this...

```xml
<style name="Button.White" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

You can use it like this...

```xml
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Button.White"
    />
```

**alternatively - using a tint**
You can simply add `android:backgroundTint` for API Level 21 and higher, or `app:backgroundTint` for API Level 7 and higher.

For more information, see [this blog](https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/android/change-android-button-color-while-maintain-effect-and-state-color/).

#### The problem with the accepted answer...

If you replace the background with a color you will loose the effect of the button, and the color will be applied to the entire area of the button. It will not respect the padding, shadow, and corner radius.

Comment: The backgroundTint is the way to go.

Comment: For some reason, both methods do not work for me. Although I can see it from the Design tab, when I run the app, it still shows me the default color. (I also tried `android:background` but did not work either.)

Comment: `theme` doesn't work, only `backgroundTint` works

Comment: @DavidLee did you found out what was the issue?

Comment: @CoryRoy Why do you believe backgroundTint is superior?

Comment: @LabGecko backgroundTint multiplies rather than replaces, so shadows etc won't be removed but still work with the new colour.

Answer (score 34):

For the **text color** add:

```
android:textColor="<hex color>"
```

For the **background color** add:

```
android:background="<hex color>"
```

From **API 21** you can use:

```
android:backgroundTint="<hex color>"
android:backgroundTintMode="<mode>"
```

---

[How to customize different buttons in Android](http://mrbool.com/how-to-customize-different-buttons-in-android/27747)

Comment: @PayelSenapati kinda stocked my answer is still reputable eventhough it's from 2015 haha

Comment: I think this is the good answer self explaining when to use backgound and when to use backgroundTint.

Comment: broken link....

Comment: Not just a broken link, but hackable, putting those who click it at risk

Comment: Tried to edit the answer to fix the link, but got "Too many edits pending. Try again later."  
So, here's a (probably) useful link on buttons. 
Don't forget to look at the Material and Compose suggestions. https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/components/button

Answer (score 8):

#### Many great methods presented above - One newer note

It appears that there was a bug in earlier versions of Material that prevented certain types of overriding the button color.

See: [[Button] android:background not working #889](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/issues/889)

I am using today Material 1.3.0. I just followed the direction of KavinduDissanayake in the linked post and used this format:

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/purple_700"
```

(I changed the chosen color to my own theme of course.) This solution worked very simply for me.

Answer (score 7):

If the first solution doesn't work try this:

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
```

I hope this work.
Happy coding.

Comment: This didn't work for me today. using app: instead of android: as suggested by @zFreeindeed fixed it

Comment: this code worked for me, its changes the background color of the button

Answer (score 5):

**Here is my code, to make different colors on button, and Linear, Constraint and Scroll Layout**

First, you need to make a custom_button.xml on your drawable

1. Go to res
2. Expand it, right click on drawable
3. New -> Drawable Resource File
4. File Name : custom_button, Click OK

**Custom_Button.xml Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/> <!-- pressed -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/blue"/> <!-- focused -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/black"/> <!-- default -->
</selector>
```

Second, go to res

1. Expand values
2. Double click on colors.xml
3. Copy the code below

**Colors.xml Code**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF4081</color>

    <color name="black">#000</color>
    <color name="violet">#9400D3</color>
    <color name="indigo">#4B0082</color>
    <color name="blue">#0000FF</color>
    <color name="green">#00FF00</color>
    <color name="yellow">#FFFF00</color>
    <color name="orange">#FF7F00</color>
    <color name="red">#FF0000</color>
</resources>
```

**Screenshots below**

[image]
    XML Coding
[image]
    Design Preview

Answer (score 4):

Starting with API 23, you can do:

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOffWhite));
```

and your colors.xml must contain:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorOffWhite">#80ffffff</color>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 4):

Best way to change button color without losing button ghosting and other features.

Try it and you will see it is the best

```
app:backgroundTint="@color/color_name"
```

Answer (score 2):

in theme change this:
parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar"
to that:
parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar"

It worked for me after many search

Answer (score 2):

usually with API 21 and above :
just PUT this attribute : android:backgroundTint=" your color "

Answer (score 2):

i'm using api 32 and I had to do it this way in the xml code:

```
android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the value in the XML like this:

```
<Button
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
     ../>
```

Here, you can add any other color, from the resources or hex.

Similarly, you can also change these values form the code like this:

```
demoButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Another easy way is to make a drawable, customize the corners and shape according to your preference and set the background color and stroke of the drawable.
For eg.

button_background.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="#ff207d94" />
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF" />
</shape>
```

And then set this shape as the background of your button.

```
<Button
    android:background="@drawable/button_background.xml"
     ../>
```

Hope this helps, good luck!

Answer (score 1):

see the image and easy understand

[image: image use]

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is better to code instead of sending a screenshot

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Answer (score 1):

1. in new update of android studio you have to change the

**button  -> androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton**

then only the button color will changed

**res/drawable/button_color_border.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >

    <solid android:color="#FFDA8200" />

    <stroke
        android:width="3dp"
        android:color="#FFFF4917" />

</shape>
```

And add button to your XML activity layout and set background
**android:background="@drawable/button_color_border".**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/button_border"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Answer (score 1):

**Use below code for button background color**

```
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_rounded);
```

here is drawable xml

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle" >
            <solid android:color="@color/gray_scale_color"/>
            <corners android:radius="@dimen/_12sdp"/>

            <stroke android:width="0.5dp"
                android:color="?attr/appbackgroundColor"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to set the background as some other resource file in your drawable folder, say, a *custom-button.xml*, then try this:

```
button_name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button_file_name);
```

eg. Say, you have a *custom-button.xml* file. Then,

```
button_name.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button);
```

Will set the button background as the *custom-button.xml* file.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem
the solution for me was the background color was colorPrimary of my theme
you can use custom theme as one answer say above and set the colorPrimary to what you want

1- add this to your "value/themes/themes.xml" inside resources

```xml
<resources>
   <style name="Button.color" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat">
       <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
   </style>
</resources>
```

2- add this line to the button you want to have the color

```
    <Button
  
      android:theme="@style/Button.color"/>
```

Comment: Please attach a code snippet or example so others can better understand your solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Go to <kbd>res</kbd> > <kbd>values</kbd> > <kbd>themes</kbd> > `theme.xml`/`themes.xml`. Then change:

```
<style name="Theme.BirthdayGreet" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

To:

```
<style name="Theme.MemeShare" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">)>
```

[Watch this video for more information.](https://youtu.be/AdlxIdYus14)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/29979636)

Comment: @Boken: This is clearly more than just a _link_ to an answer. It also includes specific guidance.

Answer (score 0):

backgroundTint above API21 background has no effect it takes colorPrimary of the theme by default

Answer (score 0):

> **Button background color in xml**

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="#0000FF"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

> **Change button background color programmatically**

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button);
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

> **Custom button background**

*shape.xml*   [`res` --> `drawble`]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
    <gradient
        android:angle="0"
        android:endColor="#0000FF"
        android:startColor="#00FFFF" />
    <stroke
        android:width="1dp"
        android:color="#000000" />
</shape>
```

*Add this line*

```
android:background="@drawable/shape"
```

*full code*

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:background="@drawable/shape"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"/>
```

> **Material Design Button**

*Change button background color*

```
app:backgroundTint="#0000FF"
```

*Button Stroke color*

```
app:strokeColor="#000000"
```

*Button Stroke width*

```
app:strokeWidth="2dp"
```

*Full code*

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    app:backgroundTint="#0000FF"
    app:strokeColor="#000000"
    app:strokeWidth="2dp"/>
```

**Hope you helpful!**

Answer (score 0):

Go to `themes.xml` file under res -> values -> themes

Go to the line -

```
<style name="Theme.YourProjectName" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

and change it to -

```
<style name="Theme.YourProjectName" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
```

Then proceed with changing

`android:backgroundTint` to desired color

Answer (score 0):

Buttons use `colorPrimary` attribute by default.

If you are styling using Theme:

```
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/yourColor</item>
```

Note that other widgets also use this attribute.

Drop any other widgets, that you know use this attribute, in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**btn_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape  android:shape="rectangle" >
            <corners android:radius="10dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

**btn_color_state.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!--    state pressed-->
    <item android:color="#94E4A2" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <!--    state Disabled-->
    <item android:color="#c5c5c5"  android:state_enabled="false"/>
    <!--    state default-->
    <item android:color="#36df54" />
</selector>
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/btn_color_state"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Hello World"
        android:enabled="false"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_bg"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/btn_color_state"
        android:layout_margin="8dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Answer (score -2):

To change the color of button programmatically

### Here it is :

```
Button b1;
//colorAccent is the resource made in the color.xml file , you can change it.
b1.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
```