# Change background color of Button in Android

Tags: java, android, android-button, material-components-android

I'm trying to change the color of a button, but it doesn't work.

*btn_sign_in.xml*

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners android:radius="23dp" />
    <size android:height="16dp" />
    <solid android:color="#045762" />
</shape>
```

and I gave `android:background="@drawable/btn_sign_in"` in the button xml.

Comment: Can you please provide your button xml?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55954610/10182897) can help you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change the color of a button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32671004/how-to-change-the-color-of-a-button)

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use a custom background.
Just use:

```
    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        app:cornerRadius="23dp"
        app:backgroundTint="#045762"
        android:text="BUTTON"
        .../>
```

[image]

Comment: That worked. I need to give shadow for the button too. giving elevation doesn't seem to work. is there any other way?

Comment: Use `app:elevation` instead of `android:elevation`

Answer (score 0):

hi have you tried `app:backgroundTint="#045762"`, this will work in may cases but if u have to use a drawable then do this

```
app:backgroundTint="@null"
android:background="@drawable/btn_sign_in"
```

When using MatertialComponents Background tint will be given priority over the background and in your case, you can try to pass color directly as backgroundTint

also check out MaterialButton from MaterialComponents

Comment: I also need to give elevation for the button, giving elevation to the button doesn't seem to work

Comment: u can give elevation to MaterialButton check out https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons and by default, Material buttons have elevation and inSet already applied

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background color like this.

```
<Button
    android:background="@android:color/green"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

XML:

```
<Button
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>
```

Programmatically:

```
btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
btn.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
```